# iOS game development: how do I use NavigationView buttons to call a function from another class?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm brand new to Swift programming, and have pulled together a couple tutorials to try to make a simple Minesweeper iOS app. I want to have a menu at the bottom with an option to reset the board. I have a function in Game.swift that resets the board, and the main navigation is in MinesweeperApp.swift. I can't figure out how to call the reset function from the navigation without getting an error.

My project structure is as such:

```
Minesweeper
  ├ View
  | ├ CellView.swift
  | └ BoardView.swift
  ├ Model
  | ├ GameSettings.swift
  | ├ Game.swift
  | ├ Cell.swift
  | └ Cell+Swift.swift
  ├ Shared
  | ├ Assets.xcassets
  | ├ MinesweeperApp.swift
  | └ ContentView.swift
```

My Game.swift file:

```
class Game: ObservableObject {
    
    // the game settings
    @Published var settings: GameSettings
    @Published var board: [[Cell]]
    
    init(from settings: GameSettings) {
        self.settings = settings
        self.board = Game.GenerateBoard(from: settings)
    }

    ... etc ...

    func resetBoard() {
        self.board = Game.GenerateBoard(from: settings)
    }
```

My MinesweeperApp.swift file:

```
@main
struct MinesweeperApp: App {
    var gameSettings = GameSettings() // the game settings
    
    var body: some Scene {
        
        WindowGroup {
            NavigationView {
                BoardView() // our content view
                    .environmentObject(Game(from: gameSettings)).padding()
                    .navigationTitle("Minesweeper")
                    .toolbar {
                        ToolbarItem(placement: .bottomBar) {
                            Button("Reset") {
                                Game.resetBoard()
                                print("Pressed")
                            }
                        }
                    }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

When I take out the line Game.resetBoard() in MinesweeperApp, it works correctly and prints 'pressed'. When I add that line in, the error I'm getting says

```
Instance member 'resetBoard' cannot be used on type 'Game'; did you mean to use a value of this type instead?
```

So, I'm trying to figure out how/where to call the reset function correctly.

The tutorials I used are

- Minesweeper: https://levelup.gitconnected.com/swiftui-minesweeper-cd145f888343
- Adding a navigation menu: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-create-a-toolbar-and-add-buttons-to-it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now, because you're creating your instance of `Game` *inside* the `environmentObject` call, you don't have a reference stored at the `App` level to manipulate.

The easiest fix would be this:

```
@main
struct MinesweeperApp: App {
    var game = Game(from: GameSettings())
    
    var body: some Scene {
        
        WindowGroup {
            NavigationView {
                BoardView() // our content view
                    .environmentObject(game)
                    .padding()
                    .navigationTitle("Minesweeper")
                    .toolbar {
                        ToolbarItem(placement: .bottomBar) {
                            Button("Reset") {
                                game.resetBoard() //<-- Here
                                print("Pressed")
                            }
                        }
                    }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Then, you can call `resetBoard` on the *instance* of `Game` rather than trying to call it on the type (which is why you're getting the error right now).

This, of course, would depend on your sub views (like `Board`) using `@EnvironmentObject var game : Game` instead of `@EnvironmentObject var gameSettings : GameSettings`. And, you would access the settings in your subviews by doing `game.settings`

Answer (score 1):

Game = Class Game which cannot call non-static functions. You need to create Object before using ".resetBoard()" and I think it will be on top of your MinesweeperApp.

```
struct MinesweeperApp: App {
var gameSettings = GameSettings() // the game settings

//...
var game = Game(from settings: gameSettings)

var body: some Scene {
```